# Is it possible to access google map instance without making it a global variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, npm

The google map API documents use the `script` tags to access the google map instance which makes it a global variable. Is it possible to access the map instance without it being global?

The `angular-google-maps` npm/bower package doesn't use script tags, but unfortunately it is unmaintained now which is why the project I'm working on is migrating away from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the map into a module.

For example,

```
var app = (function(){

    var map = null;
    var init = function(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: {lat:1, lng:1}
        });

    return {
        init: init
    };

})();
```

And then in your HTML script tag:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=app.init"></script>
```

Your "app" module would have to be "global", but only because it is necessary. I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but this is what first came to mind.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that the google map object is still being retrieved from the global space. I think what I'm after I will find by looking under the hood in the "angular-google-maps" source code. That package doesn't use a script tag to receive it.